# Wrong Tire Pressure After Walmart Installation. Intentional?

Tags: tires, wheels, tire-pressure, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I bought set of BFGoodrich g-Force COMP-2 all-seasons listed as new, and just had them installed at my local Walmart Auto Care Center. Service time was 2 hours and 20 minutes (is that normal?). Front set are supposed to be 30 psi and rear should be 40 according to the door sticker and manual. As I drove off, TPMS measured 38 for FL, 38 FR, 36 RL and 37 RR... Got home and verified with two different tire pressure gauges.

The invoice they handed me lists the following service descriptions:

- Tire Pressure - Drv Rear - CHECKED. 36
- Tire Pressure - Pass Rear - CHECKED. 36
- Tire Pressure - Drv Front - CHECKED. 36
- Tire Pressure - Pass Front - CHECKED. 36

Also of note was this line:

- Battery Check - DECLINED
   **Unsafe environment**

Car is a 2012 Mercedes-Benz C250. They also did TPMS resets and balancing. Should I correct the tire pressure immediately or leave them as they are? What should I look out for after a new tire installation? Also, how do I determine if tires ordered from walmart.com are genuinely new?

Answer (score 3):

Please correct the tire pressure as soon as you can.
They likely couldn't be bothered to look up the correct values for your car and chose to use reasonable "default" ones.
It still is safe to drive like this, but there'll be a bit more wear on the rear tires, and the front may feel less stable.

After having driven a few miles, you should make sure the wheel bolts are still tight.

The definition of "new" tires depends a bit on your location - in some countries, tires still count as "new" even when (properly) stored for a few years.
As a general indicator, you can compare the looks of your tires with online pictures.
On the tires, you should also find a four digit number, encased in an oval - that's the DOT code. The first two digits refer to the calender week, the last two digits to the year of manufacture. If those are reasonably new, the tires have probably not been used before.

A 2:20h service time might be a bit long, but not excessive considering the time of the year and potential high workload.